# Can someone download my code of my mobile application from Play Store?

Tags: android, security

Can someone download the code of my mobile application in Android if I publish it into the Play Store?

If it is, how can I protect my application for this kind of attacks? Can I use something to avoid it? I don't have any idea about security but I think it's very important to prepare my app to this kind of problems.

Comment: Yes, your apk can be easily disassembled (its just a .zip), allowing someone else to get at the resources and .class files (which are also easily decompiled back to .java). I think the recommended solution is to obfuscate with Proguard to make things more difficult, but there is no fullproof protection.

Comment: @trooper Thank you for answer!. But I don't understand why too much negative votes. What I did wrong?

Comment: @Error404 you are getting down votes because its offtopic. SO is for programming questions and this is a question for decompiling an `.apk`.

Answer (score 4):

Everyone can just download your app, save it to his pc in an apk file format and use an app like `dex2jar` or `apktool` to get all the app contents. It would take around 1 hour and it isn't that difficult. You can use proguard to obfuscate the code of your app to make it alot harder to use the decompiled code as for Example MainActivity.class would get a.class.

Enable proguard in android studio:
`build.gradle (app):`

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

`proguard-rules.pro`:

```
-optimizationpasses 5

-dontusemixedcaseclassnames

-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses

-dontpreverify

-verbose

-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService


-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** v(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    public void set*(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}
```

Comment: And do you know another tool for obfuscate my code? I never did it and I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Are you using android studio for developing?

Comment: Yes, I am. Why? It is a bad idea?

Comment: Nono, you can just enable proguard in your release settings and it will obfuscate the code for you during the release build progress. I edited my question

Comment: @qwertz "I edited my question"  should be "I edited my answer" ;)

Comment: @SuperThomasLab haha sorry, derp :P